# Starling + Robotlegs - only first mediator instantiating

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework, robotlegs

I am having problems with using the latest version of Starling with Robotlegs.

I am finding it all compiles but only my first mediator is instantiated.

http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/discussions/problems/389-robotlegs-support-starling-framework

http://omar.likesflex.com/?p=54#comments

I have set `autoStartup=true` in my context, and have tried and have tried with swc and sourcecode versions. I have also tried changing event `bubbles=true` in the starling sourcecode as someone suggested, nothing seems to work.

If I replace the Robot-Starling-Plugin (https://github.com/s9tpepper/robotlegs-starling-plugin) with the sourcecode after fixing the following bug I still have the same issue.
https://github.com/s9tpepper/robotlegs-starling-plugin/issues/13

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had success with this extension
https://github.com/jamieowen/robotlegs2-starling-viewmap